# Alternative to jQuery Lint?

Tags: jquery, jquery-lint

I'm wondering if there is an alternative to jQuery Lint which is able to perform static analysis rather than runtime/in-browser analysis, i.e. I want a tool which doesn't need to run in a browser and can analyse the source code of an entire project.

My problem is that I have a large number of pages/scripts using a few different versions of jQuery ranging from 1.2 up to 1.7 and I want to migrate them all to the latest version of jQuery. But before I do that, I want to know if the code is using any deprecated/removed jQuery functionality or using jQuery in a way that has changed since version 1.2, e.g. [@attr] style selectors which were removed in jQuery v1.3.

It is not feasible for me to open every single page and follow every execution path using jQuery Lint to get its output.

Comment: jQuery is mostly backwards-compatible. I don't think they removed a single "public" function yet.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I've edited my question to make it clear that I also want to know if I'm using jQuery selectors and functions in a way that has changed. I think there are at least a couple examples of things like that which have changed.

Comment: But they did change some behaviour, I think it's wrong to just imply you can switch jquery versions and be done with it. I know for a fact that switching from 1.3 to 1.7 got some of our pages in trouble (had something to do with events), so I would advice strongly against "no need for worry, no public function removed" based steps